# How to match multiple words with hyphen in perl regexp

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to know how to match multiple words (contains space) separated by hyphen in a url using perl regular expressions. For example,

```
url = &name=abc&age=12&address=ab - cd&city=xyz;
url = &name=abc&age=12&address=abcd&city=xyz;
```

In the given url, I would like to match the address field alone and replace it with empty.

I am trying this but it is not matching the hyphen and the words followed from first url but it is working fine for second url.

```
url =~ s/\&address=(\w+)//g;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$url =~ s/\&address=([^&]+)//g;`

Comment: @mpapec Wont that remove fragments if they exist and address is the final parameter?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen it should remove one or more `non-&` chars. `?address=..` will fail though.

Comment: please mention the exact desired output that would help to provide answer..

Comment: I would like to remove the address field completely from the url. From url = &name=abc&age=12&address=ab - cd&city=xyz; to url = &name=abc&age=12&city=xyz;

Comment: mark as answered ...the solutions which u feel is suitable for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regular expression is a decent approach, but it has to potential to destroy the integrity of your URLs by potentially removing additional information that might be important (e.g. fragments).

An alternative approach would be to use the [`URI::QueryParam`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI%3a%3aQueryParam) module to overwrite the value with nothing:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use URI;
use URI::QueryParam;

my $url = 'http://www.domain.com/a/b/c?name=abc&age=12&address=ab - cd&city=xyz';
my $uri = URI->new($url);

$uri->query_param('address', '');
print "Address is now: " . $uri->query_param('address') . "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these by un-commenting and should work for you , for more help please comment with desired output you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$url = '&name=abc&age=12&address=ab - cd&city=xyz';
$url = '&name=abc&age=12&address=abcd&city=xyz';
$url =~ s/address=(.*)&//g;
#$url =~ s/address=(.*)&/$1/g;
print $url;
```